# Как исключить из возвращаемых значений и полностью удалить определенный ключ в Request?

Tags: php, laravel

Добрый день, есть пару вопросов по фреймворку Laravel

1) Имеется массив:

```
array(3) { ["brand"]=> string(3) "1,2" ["type"]=> string(1) "6" ["page"]=> string(1) "2" }
```

Получаю его вот так: `$request->input();`

Как из этого массива исключить `['page']?`

2) Имеется ссылка вида (текущая)

```
site.com/category/cars?brand=2,3,4&type=1,8&page=2
```

Вывожу ее в шаблоне вот так

```
<?php echo $request->fullUrl(); ?>
```

Как сделать, что бы эта функция выводила вот это:

```
site.com/category/cars?brand=2,3,4&type=1,8
```

А не вот это:

```
site.com/category/cars?brand=2,3,4&type=1,8&page=2
```

То есть как исключить &page=2?

Comment: Разве `unset` не работает?

Comment: Можете пожалуйста продемонстрировать пример

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.unset.php

Answer (score 2):

Для исключения ключей из возвращаемых значений, нужно воспользоваться методом `except()` следующим образом:

```
$data = $request->except(['page']);
```

Такой код вернет то же самое, что и `Request::input()`, кроме ключа `page`.

---

Чтобы удалить какой-либо ключ из из `Request` вовсе, потребуется такой код:

```
$request->offsetUnset('page');
```

После чего уже можно использовать:

```
<?php echo $request->fullUrl(); ?>
```